# AS3 how to hide the movie clip array items except the clicked one?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have a buttons menu and i want to hide all the buttons except the clicked one, anybody can help please?

Code:

```
var _objects:Array = new Array();
var total:Number = sympols_mc.numChildren;
var i:uint;


for( i = 0; i < total; i++ )
{
    _objects.push(sympols_mc.getChildAt(i));

    _objects[i].btn_icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_CLICK);
};

function btn_CLICK(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    for( i = 0; i < total; i++ )
    {
        //for example:
        _objects[i].btn_icon.visible = false; //I want to keep the visibility of the clicked button (e.target.parent.btn_icon) = true.
    };
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `visible`...

```
function btn_CLICK(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    for( i = 0; i < total; i++ )
    {
        _objects[i].btn_icon.visible = false;
    }
    e.target.parent.btn_icon.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for an other code for example if I want to animate the buttons instead of hide then this code will apply the motion tween to all children of the array..

Comment: I have an idea but I don't know how to code it properly. I want to remove the target.parent from the array.. we use "push" to add an items but whech code can remove it? I tried "slice" and "splice" but nothing happened!